# Ratio test versus root test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers. Then one can use (among other) the root test and the ratio test to test the convergence of $\sum a_n$. I am looking for a sequence $(a_n)$ such that both $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ and $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ exist and such that either

1. $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ can be determined easily and $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is hard to determine

or

2. $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ can be determined easily and $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ is hard to determine.

Here by "easy" I mean that the limit can be determined with tools from an introductory course in calculus, and by "hard" I mean that one needs more/deeper tools. Does anyone know an example of 1. or 2. (or both)?

Comment: Do you know that both ratio and root test give the same limit?

Comment: This looks like someone is writing a test or an example for class ...

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that factorials are going to be better with the ratio test than the root test, whereas powers are better for the root test.

Comment: When both limits exist, they give the same value. But generically it is possible for the root-test limit to exist and the ratio-test limit to not exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

In general we have:

> If $a_n>0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then$$\liminf\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq \liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq \limsup\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

Ok take for instance the sequence $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$

You can prove that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to \frac{1}{e}<1$

But it is more difficult to compute the limit of $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$

For the other way around its easier for instance for the sequence $a_n=\frac{n^{n+1}}{2^n}$ to use the $n-$th root test than the ratio test.

Comment: I'm not sure that the ratio test is any more difficult for $a_n = n^{n + 1}2^{-n}$ than for $a_n = n!n^{-n}$; we have in the first case that $a_{n + 1}a_n^{-1}$ equals $(n + 1)^2(1 + 1/n)^n/(2n)$, which it is easy to see tends to $\infty$.